# Fail to run sharepoint 2010 workflow with custom action

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sandbox-solution

I have a workflow custom action which deployed as sandboxes solution. However, when i trying to start this workflow, the error message appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you provided , There seem to be multiple things that can cause this , please follow the below blog and try the solution .

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2011/02/08/error-the-sandboxed-code-execution-request-was-refused-because-the-sandboxed-code-host-service-was-too-busy-to-handle-the-request-ricky-kirkham/